# EaselJS Slow performance on ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, ios7, easeljs

been searching for a while on this.

We've built an EaselJS game that is supposed to work on mobile aswell, we have great performance on Android and on IOS6 (iPhone4) no matter which device I use with iOS 7 (iPhone, iPad) the performance goes down the drain. the game is just not playable anymore.

Basically we have a boat that needs to avoid obstacles, therefore we have a hittest running when the objects come close to each other. The objects do switch the container so we have a fluid animation and proper hittesting, we are pooling objects and we have a clean removal of objects.

Seems to me like there are problems with Canvas performance on iOS 7, did anyone else experience this? What annoys me most is that the same game works perfect on an iPhone4 with iOS 6